# Eloquent filter on method

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables items and naws.
With

```
Item::where( 'items.item_type' , '=' , $pagetype)->get();
```

I retrieve the object perfect, but now i wan t to filter on **area** in the **naws** table.
How can i achieve that?

Model Item:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';

    public function naw()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Naw');
    }

}
```

[image: Item table]

[image: Name address ....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awnser:

```
    return Item::with([
        'naw' => function($query) use ($slug)
        {
            $query->whereArea($slug);
        }
    ])->where( 'items.item_type' , '=' , $pagetype)->get();
```